# Core Plot Reload Data

Tags: ios, core-plot

Beginner in Core Plot,I'm trying to plot real time graph using core plot where the data comes every 0.3 second and I am plotting for about 1 hour duration. Now every time when the reload data method is called does core plot start plotting the graph all over or only the newly appended point in the datasource is considered?What I am targeting is only the newly appended point to be reloaded to be plotted on the plot and the rest points in datasource already plotted without reloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options for updating the plot data:

- `-reloadData`: Queries the datasource for all of the data points.
- `-insertDataAtIndex:numberOfRecords:`: Insert records into the plot data cache at the given index. The datasource is only queried for the new data. Use a starting index equal to the old data count to append records to the end of the existing data set.
- `-reloadDataInIndexRange:`: Refresh only the data points in the given range.
- `-deleteDataInIndexRange:`: Removes existing data int the given range.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Will try out the different options suggested.

Comment: Any example that demonstrates the use of insertDataAtIndex method in case of a Real time graph would be of great help sir.

Comment: There is one in the "Real Time Plot" in the *Plot Gallery* example app. The example just plots random data, but that's easily changed to a different source of data.

Comment: Will go through the one suggested.Thanks for the help sir.